# Difficulty to find any preimages $a$ and $b$ for given $V$ so that $H(a) \oplus H(b) = V$?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, xor, sha-2

Suppose I have the values $a$, $b$, and $V = H(a) \oplus H(b)$ with inputs $a \neq b$ and $H$ being SHA-224. None of these values are a secret.
How secure is it to assume that no other possible values $a'$ and $b'$ (except the case of $a'=b$ and $b'=a$) can be generated that result in the same $V = H(a') \oplus H(b')$?

Are there recommended procedures to combine two hashes into a single value and meet the following properties:

1. $V$ has same (or nearly same) size as each of both input hashes
2. Any single unknown value ($V$, $H(a)$, or $H(b)$) can easily be deduced from two known values.
3. Cryptographically hard to obtain different pre-images $a'$ and $b'$ with same $V$

Comment: If you are using SHA-224 then an attacker can find $a'$ and $b'$ in $2^{112}$ work by using a birthday attack to find $a'$ and $b'$ where $H(a') \oplus H(b') = V$

Comment: @user13741: your statement requires an _about_ to become correct. In order to reach odds of success $1/2$, over $1/6$ more than $2^{112}$ evaluations of $H$ are required, even if the adversary had arbitrarily large and fast memory; and since that's not, and such huge search (much larger than all bitcoin mining done to that day) needs to be distributed, significantly more hashing is required.

Comment: @user13741 Would you explain more please? The values of $a$ and $b$ are fixed, so how does the birthday expected complexity hold? It is like a case of second-preimage to me.

Comment: @saeedn A birthday attack can be used because we do not need to find a specific hash (like a preimage or 2nd-preimage), we just need to find any two hashes which have a specific xor difference.

Answer (score 1):

$ Pr(H(a) \oplus H(b) = V)$ is independent of $V$ For a good hash, as pointed out in the comments. Pick your input space to be the output space of SHA-224 so with probability $1/2$ (1) holds.

The range of $H$ is a group under $\oplus$. So (2) holds.

3 won't hold by the same group property. Another $2^{112}$ trials will likely yield $a',b'$ satisfying (3) with probability $1/2$.

Comment: Why do you say (3) won't hold? 112 bits is enough to be infeasible for a *long* time, even if not necessarily forever like the 224-bit preimage resistance (without breaks, of course).

Comment: I meant  different preimages are no more costly than the original preimages.